# C#: Compare a Regex string with groups

Tags: c#, regex, match, regex-group

I have this string: `{test1}-{test2}/{x+y}`

I want to check whether `{test1}{test}` matches that string.

It WOULD match if I just could ignore the chars between the `}...{`

How would you write that Regex?

UPDATE:

I want to check whether `{test1}{test2}{x+y}` matches the string:

`{test1}-{test2}/{x+y}`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to see if the string contains {test1}, followed by something, then followed by {test}? The input string contains "{test2}" as the second string there, that wouldn't match would it?

Comment: ups sorry Lasse I correct: {test1}{test2}{x+y} is the string that must match!

Comment: Awaiting the correction then. Please edit your question so that it correctly portrays what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I'm pretty sure you don't really want it like that. Please leave comments and *edit your question* to indicate what you rally want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your comment means that you want to use the following pattern `{test1}{test2}{x+y}` and you want it to match the first string, with the additional rule that between the braced groups you can provide anything, so the minus and the division there should not prevent a match.

To match the input, which can contain arbitrary characters between the braced groups, use this type of regular expression:

```
\{test1\}.*\{test2\}.*\{x\+y\}
```

This will match:

```
{test1}{test2}{x+y}
{test1}-{test2}/{x+y}

{test1}+{test3}*{test2}/{test4}-{x-y}+{x+y}
       ---------       ---------------           <-- the parts that match .*
```

Comment: shouldn't you escape braces as well?

Comment: Good catch, but not necessary here though it is correct to do it. A brace only specifies a repetition when it contains a number, so `x{t}` does not mean "x 't' times", but `x{2}` would. Will edit.

Comment: well my braces contains test"1" and test"2" also a number but not a standalone number. So I guess for test2 I do not need braces right?

Comment: the backslashes for the braces are NOT needed :)

Comment: I know, so now I got two people, one wants the braces escaped (which technically is both right and wrong), the other says they're not necessary to escape (which is technically both right and wrong). I'll leave it as-is. If you feel strongly about it, edit the answer.